# Troubleshooting Image Recognition Neural Network Issues

Tags: java, image-processing, neural-network

Thanks in advance for reading this.

So I'm attempting to write a neural network for recognizing a specific logo within an image. I basically have a sliding window of a specific aspect ratio that will scale the current window to the expected size of the input. The window slides around pumping input into the network, and looking at the output to determine if what's in the window is the logo that I'm looking for. In that case, it will draw a box around the edge of the window, outlining the logo.

My problem resides in the fact that the neural network reports way too high of confidence for other parts of the image, and will end up drawing so many boxes all over the place, that it's impossible to see much of the original image. So there is obviously something wrong with the neural network.

For inputting the image, I have tried unrolling as grayscale, and as color. It doesn't work either way. I've tried variations on the input size as well. When it starts to get too small, then it will get worse, but even at 57x22x3 colored unrolled input, it still fails.

So I don't think that's the issue either. My neural network has X input neurons (where X is width * height * num_colors). I have one hidden layer, also of size X, and finally, I have 1 output neuron in the output layer, outputting a value between 0.0 and 1.0, representing the total confidence.

I have 17 positive training examples (ideal output is a 1.0), and 19 negative training examples (ideal output is a 0.0). After training, the network reports nearly equal confidence of ~0.95 for all positive, and nearly equal confidence of ~0.013 for all negative examples.

My theory is the number of training examples I have is far too small, and I should collect/generate more. I had only 5 of each initially, but I didn't see any gains from going up to 17+ either.

I should note I've tried using Encog and Neuroph, and both have extremely similar results. I'm using backpropagation for learning, and have tried using learning rates between 0.3 and 0.7, as well as momentum values between 0.0 and 0.8. Regardless, the result is almost always the same.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using any auto-associative memory NN architectures? Especially if you have only one (or few) well-defined logo(s).

Comment: I'm curious on why you decided to use NN for this task. Would you bother explaining your reasoning to me ?

Comment: For a class project on Machine Learning. I thought it would be fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually neural networks do require a lot of samples for learning, but can't say for sure that this is your problem.

Maybe a better idea for you to do matching is to find percent match for each pixel in your pattern vs the pixel where the pattern could be in the image given (for example use sliding window style).

If you have an array of pixel colours to match your pattern against:

> 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF

and a pattern with these pixel colours:

> 0xEE0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0101DE

You can get a delta in % for each pixel, then average them. Now there are multiple way you could average (weighted averages, exponentially weighted average, etc). At the end you can get a percent match for the entire pattern: how well the pattern matches the current pixels in the sliding window. You can always keep track of the maximum score are so at the end you display only one box (the one which has the highest probability of matching the patter).

You can create a neuron for each pixel, and the dendrites can be different part of the the colour hex number. Maybe a dendrite for each R,G,B. In the example I gave above I took one dendrite for the whole colour integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SOM/LVQ neural network for classifying the sliding window input this matlab post should give u some ideas http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/image-classification-using-matlab-somlvq/